# iPhone - 3 UITableViews with Custom cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm having a view with 3 Table views.
Each table view will use one "Custom Cell View". I'm using the following code. But its showing only one table view. Can some one point me why? (All the arrays are filled with necessary objects)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString* cellID = @"CustomSyncCell";
CustomCellView* cell = (CustomCellView*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if(cell == nil)
{
    NSArray* nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellView" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in nibObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCellView class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomCellView*)currentObject;
        }
    }       
}

ObjectDetails* obj;
if(tableView == phoneNumbersTable)
{
    obj = [phoneNumbersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if(tableView == mailIDsTable)
{
    obj = [mailIDsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if(tableView == socialUpdatesTable)
{
    obj = [socialUpdatesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}   

cell.keyLabel.text = [self returnPhoneType:obj.objKey];
cell.valueLabel.text = obj.objValue;        

return cell;}
```

Comment: Are all three visible at once?  Is the delegate and datasource set for all three table views?  What do the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection methods look like?

Comment: Yes, all the three are visible at a time. for all the tableviews delegate and datasources are set. number of sections in table view is 1 and number of rows are array count.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. Set tag property on your tableViews and in the dataSource and Delegates methods test for that tag.
2. Make 3 objects and each objet set it for is specific tableView delegate and data source and put your code in that objects.

Hope that helps. If you will add all your data source and delegate methods more people will try to help.

Comment: for option 1: i'm checking the tableview directly so how does tags help. And for option 2: i don't think this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the reuse identifier. Since you are using the cell with the same identifier for all the table views so, I think that is the cause of the problem. I also had this problem fixed it with the same manner. Create separate cells for each tableview with different identifier and reuse them.